# drupal s3 file url from raw node

Tags: drupal, amazon-s3, drupal-7

I'm trying to get an S3 external URL from a raw drupal 7 node.  I know that I need to hand this off to the amazons3 module, but I don't know how to go about doing that, and I can't find any documentation on it.  Right now if I access the file field, there is only an s3 url stored there.  I just need to find a way to convert it to a public s3 url.  Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  Use this, pass in the raw s3 uri.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7